# How do I declare NULL/Void in swift when I don't need to use a completion block?

Tags: objective-c, swift, objective-c-blocks

**Here is the code in objective-c:**

```
[self presentViewController:logInViewController animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

My code so far in swift:

```
self.presentViewController(logInViewController, animated: true, completion:  )
```

Thought it would be as straight forward as typing "Void". Unfortunately there's a little more to it.

Comment: Wouldn't `nil` work?

Comment: @KevinDiTraglia Originally tried but it didn't work but now I can see it was an autocomplete problem. The autocomplete in XCode 6 is a little funky. Haven't got used to it.

Comment: You should use nil for both Swift [and Objective C](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5766292/300836). It's sensible, *and* it's easy to remember...

Comment: But, `nil` can only be used if the completion block is optional.  In this specific case (probably in most UIKit cases) the block is invoked as `(()->Void)!` so it's an explicitly unwrapped optional and takes nil.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apple's prerelease documentation says:

```
func presentViewController(_ viewControllerToPresent: UIViewController!,
                                       animated flag: Bool,
                               completion completion: (() -> Void)!)
```

**Parameters**

```
viewControllerToPresent
```

The view controller to display over the current view controller’s content.

```
flag
```

Pass true to animate the presentation; otherwise, pass false.

```
completion
```

The block to execute after the presentation finishes. This block has no return value and takes no parameters. **You may specify nil for this parameter.**

Therefore you can specify `nil` for this parameter.

You can access this prerelease documentation from your `iOS Dev Center`