# UIImageView drag and touch

Tags: ios

I would like to detect drag and touch on a uiimageview.
How do i do that?
I need to implement code like this in the event for image flipping.
[iOS 4.2: Flip image using block animations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737878/ios-4-2-flip-image-using-block-animations)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for drag and touch for your Image View you have to assign GestureRecognizer

```
//drag your object
UIPanGestureRecognizer *panRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(panDetected:)];
[self.imageSubVw addGestureRecognizer:panRecognizer];

// scale your object
UIPinchGestureRecognizer *pinchRecognizer = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(pinchDetected:)];
[self.imageSubVw addGestureRecognizer:pinchRecognizer];

// rotate your object
UIRotationGestureRecognizer *rotationRecognizer = [[UIRotationGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(rotationDetected:)];
[self.imageSubVw addGestureRecognizer:rotationRecognizer];

panRecognizer.delegate = self;
pinchRecognizer.delegate = self;
rotationRecognizer.delegate = self;
```